# How to connect Ubuntu 21.10 to tagged VLAN (netplan)

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, netplan, network-bridge, vlan

I have network

```
VLAN:      4005
MTU:       1400
Subnet:    157.XX.XX.64/27
Gateway:   157.XX.XX.65
Netmask:   255.255.255.224
Broadcast: 157.XX.XX.95
```

I want to configure netplan Ubuntu 21.10 to IP 157.XX.XX.87

I have only two idea

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
     ens3:
      dhcp: false
      optional: true
 bridges: 
   br2:
     interfaces:
     addresses: 
     - 157.XX.XX.87/32
vlans:
    vlan.4005:
    id: 4005
    link: ens3
    routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 157.XX.XX.65
         metric: 100
    mtu:1400
```

other idea

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
     ens3:
      dhcp: false
      optional: true
      addresses: 
      - 157.XX.XX.87/32
 bridges: 
   br2:
     interfaces:
     addresses: 
     - 157.XX.XX.64/27
vlans:
    vlan.4005:
    id: 4005
    link: ens3
    routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 157.XX.XX.65
         metric: 100
    mtu:1400
```

Unfortunately, any my idea don't working. This server working under QEMU/KVM, therefore name of bridges and name of VLAN is define in KVM config.

What right place to setup ubuntu IP address in this case - in interface, in VLAN, in Bridge?

What right place so setup routes - in bridge or in VLAN?

What right place to setup MTU?

Comment: Do you want a bridge with vlan, or just the vlan?

Comment: And by the way the indentation does not fit!!!

Comment: @ThomasAichinger, thank you to attention for my question. I have a bridge with VLAN. If I use Ubuntu 16.04 it working automatically, I simple define IP/Mask/Broadcast/Gateway in /etc/network/interfaces, but I still don't understand what need in new Ubuntu 21, because netplan. If I define simple  IP/Mask/Broadcast/Gateway (in Ubuntu 16 style), modern Ubuntu don't working.

Comment: What do you mean, you "have" a bridge with vlan? Your netplan config shows you defining a bridge, but your vlan does not use it, it serves no obvious purpose, the addressing on it in your configuration is incorrect, and it doesn't relate to the initial network config you list.  What is the purpose of this bridge?

Comment: @slangasek Maybe I don't understand netplan idea at all. I have bridge inside KVM. And can manipulate it by BRCTL command. My KVM contains definition of Bridge and this machine is virtual machine. Any my virtual Ubuntu 16.04 working perfectly with this bridge. KVM Bridge add VLAN tag 4005 to any addr 157.XX.XX.64/27 and route it to main physical interface with VLAN Tag. Then datacenter communicator route tagged packages from IP range 157.XX.XX.64/27 to internet. But if I try to reproduce Ubuntu 16.04 network configuration (/etc/network/interface) by netplan I'm always failed.

Comment: Hi Alex, we have to be careful what is in guest/host, especially when I read "I have bridge inside KVM". You can achieve what you want in two ways "network -> ethev (tags vlan) -> host-bridge -> guest" or "network -> ethdev -> host-bridge -> guest (tags vlan)". Yours sounds a bit like the latter, which isn't safe (the guest can access all). OTOH the first approach doesn't need a bridge or vlan config in the guest at all, the host ensures it is tagged and the guest can't easily escape. That is recommended and what is explained in https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges

Comment: If you are unhappy with netplan you also can turn it off and switch back to ifup/down

Comment: The misunderstandings here are not about netplan, but about how network interfaces work (guest vs host).  ifupdown is unsupported in Ubuntu 20.04 and later and it is highly recommended you not revert to it.  Please see Christian's explanation above; the use of a bridge on the KVM host does not mean you should declare a bridge in your KVM guest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    ens3:
              dhcp4: false
              dhcp6: false

  bridges:
    br0:
          interfaces: [ens3]
          addresses: [157.XX.XX.87/27]
          gateway4: 157.XX.XX.65
          mtu: 1500
          nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8]
          parameters:
                stp: true
                forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  vlans:
    vlan4005:
      id: 4005
      link: ens3
```